# What is the typical implementation of react component with many form inputs when using ES6 classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the typical way to implement react component with many form inputs?

onChangeEvent on each input seems impractical.

there are no mixing in ES6 components anymore that have been used for two way binding helpers.

Or should I just use element references to read the input values when needed?

Comment: I use redux-form to help me with big forms. If u are using redux then it's worth a look.

Comment: http://redux-form.com

Comment: My advice would be to do onChange event handler (each input can call same method). In the long run it is worth it.

Comment: On top of @wintvelt's advice, I'll use `name` attribute to specify the field name and in the `onChange` function: `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })`

Answer (score 0):

I've made form with react many times, each time I came with a better way.
To keep it simple I can give you very basic idea of how you can approach it.

```
class Form extends Component
{
    fields = {};

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        let components = this.bindComponents();

        this.state = {};
        this.state.components = components;
    }

    render()
    {
        const { components } = this.state;

        return DOM.div({}, components);
    }

    bindComponents()
    {
        let children = this.props.children;

        children = React.Children.map(children, child =>
        {
            if (typeof child != "object" || !child.props)
                return child;

            let props = Object.assign({}, child.props);

            if (props.name)
            {
                props.onChange = (event) =>
                {
                    let value = event.target.value;

                    // Allow other parents to listen to this event
                    if (child.props.onChange)
                        child.props.onChange(value);

                    this.fields[props.name] = value;
                };
            }

            return React.cloneElement(child, props);
        });

        return children;
    }

    /**
     * You can use this in buttons and etc ..
     * Or like the onChange of the input you can do the same with onClick on buttons,
     * and when the button clicked you can trigger this event
     */
    onSubmit()
    {
        if (this.props.onSubmit)
            this.props.onSubmit(this.fields);
    }
}
```

Note that you want to prevent the form to cause any state changes, since if you render the actual inputs and buttons. it will cause all the components to be re-rendered .. so we can keep track on the values without really change any states. and the `onChange` that we put on the component itself reserved.